# <To dirty something> VS <To make something dirty>

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

We know that the word **dirty** as a verb means:

> - To allow something to get dirt on it.
> - **Example:** Don’t sit on the ground – **you’ll dirty your new suit.**

But the question is that l, is it a normal way to say that or it is not a common way of saying that while we can say:

> - Don’t sit on the ground – **you’ll make your new suit dirty.**

I wonder if you could explain that to me.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/181059/27840

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using "dirty" as a transitive verb is perfectly common. It might be seen as slightly more formal than using it as an adjective, but either is acceptable in writing or in conversation.

You will also often hear people use "get dirty" or "got dirty" instead of "make dirty," especially in informal conversation.